What is the correct way to use dbContext in Blazor server NavMenu.razor component?
I have a default template project, .net 8, server rendering. In this project there is a NavMenu.razor component. My goal is to add menu new items when the user is authorized. Here is what I do:
I have following services registered:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<LuahDbContext>(options =>
                                        options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={builder.Configuration["db"]}"));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LuahAuthService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ScheduleOps>();

NavMenu structure (I am not showing standard Microsoft packages):
@inject IServiceProvider ServiceProvider
@inject ScheduleOps ScheduleOps
@inject MenuService MenuService
@inject LuahAuthService AuthService

In the code section of NavMenu.razor component I have:
protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
if (firstRender)
AuthService.OnChange += HandleMenuChangeAsync;
return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
private async Task HandleMenuChangeAsync()
{
    var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    if (!authState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return;
    var userid = authState.User.FindFirst("userid").Value;

    List<Schedule> lst = null;
    try
    {
        using (var scope = ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            lst = await scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ScheduleOps>().CustomerSchedules(userid);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

The exception is thrown in the line
        lst = await scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ScheduleOps>().CustomerSchedules(userid);

and it is:
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.'
This is my latest attempt. First attempt was to use injected service ScheduleOps directly. It also accepts dbContext as a constructor parameter, managed by DI, and the error was of the same type: expired dbContext.
My question is - what I am doing wrong? Services are scoped and blazor should manage the lifecycle of these components, right? I am confused.

Why don’t you inject the LuahDbContext class directly?

Because it is injected in ScheduleOps by DI. The code is:
public class ScheduleOps
{
private LuahDbContext context;
public ScheduleOps(LuahDbContext dbContext)
{
this.context = dbContext;
}
...
}
Note that LuahdDbContext lives in LuahDb component, as well as ScheduleOps

Hmm?! You have this: builder.Services.AddDbContext(options =>
options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={builder.Configuration["db"]}")).

It should be available for injection

Do you need the scope, is that it?

I am using the scope in my latest attempt, using (var scope = ServiceProvider.CreateScope()),
see the code in the post.
My question is - why it does not work "out of the box"? I have dbContext and a Service that uses it in constructor. Both are registered as scoped with DI and life cycle should be managed by blazor internal scopes(?). Why does not it work?

You should be using an IDbContextFactory in Blazor - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#use-a-dbcontext-factory.  Creating a new scope is not the answer and will in all probability cause more problems.  Your problem is almost certainly in the code you're not showing us.  What you've shown should work.

@Shaun: thank you for the review. The problem I experienced was indeed a problem with the scope, and I fixed it by changing the DI registration of the service ScheduleOp from "Scoped" to "Transient". I still feel uneasy about this solution because it fixes the issue but does not explain why "Scoped" registration did not create new ScheduleOp instance every time the "HandleMenuChangeAsync" is called.
If anyone is interested I can provide the steps to recreate the issue, just let me know in the comments.

Registering the service component that uses dbContext as transient, not as scoped, solved the issue.
